# Journalctl seems to be ignoring since and until

Tags: logging, systemd, date, journalctl

I'm trying to get the logs of a problem that's been happening for over a week by this point.  I'm trying to use journalctl to print the logs but it doesn't seem to give me anything more or less than the past 5 days.  I've tried using since/until but it doesn't change anything.

```
(0) $ sudo journalctl --since='2018-11-01' | head -n1
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-12-03 09:17:53 CST, end at Fri 2018-12-07 18:27:14 CST. --
(0) $ sudo journalctl --since='2018-12-05' | head -n1
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-12-03 09:17:53 CST, end at Fri 2018-12-07 18:27:23 CST. --
(0) $ sudo journalctl --until='2018-12-04' | head -n1
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-12-03 09:17:53 CST, end at Fri 2018-12-07 18:28:40 CST. --
```

What;s especially weird is I can't even shrink the date range, so it's not an issue with logs not being stored back that far.  Does anyone know why journalctl would seem to ignore these flags?

Some system information:

```
(1) $ journalctl --version
systemd 232
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
(0) $ uname -a
Linux linux-01 4.9.0-8-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: So far I ended up writing a bash loop to manually concatenate the files I need together.  It worked but I feel this this deserves a proper solution which I have yet to find.

Comment: Did you find out why the "--since" flag is getting ignored? I have the same problem, and it seems we are the only to that have this problem.

Comment: @soulflyman Unfortunately no.  I found a workaround, which was to manually grab all the log files, sort them by date, filter them for the information I need, and concatenate them together.